# How to refresh the list view items

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms Listview. Here I have a ListView in view1. The Item for the Listview will be given from View2.

I have single ViewModel for View1 and View2. After adding the item details I am trying to load the listView items before going to the View1 from view2.

Functionally everything is fine but the View1 is not updating from view2.

What I did so far:

-Using ObservableCollection for `ListView`

-Updating from View2:

```
// Calling this from View2
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    await LoadListViewDetails();
});
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Can you please post your code for `LoadListViewDetails()`?

Comment: `ListViewItemSource= new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

var listFromServer=SomeService.Instance.DetailsFromServer();

if(listFromServer?.Count>0)
{
ListViewItemSource=listFromServer;
}`

this is how the `LoadListViewDetails()` implementation like @DennisSchröer

Comment: How are `View1` and `View2` displayed? Is this a Master/Detail Page or do you navigate back from `View2` to `View1`?

Comment: THose are just content pages. I am using `await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();` to navigate from `View2` to `View1`

Comment: How are you setting the `BindingContext` for two Views ? I just want to make sure both Views are using the same instance of the `ViewModel`

Comment: do you mean ,you will add the data into viewmodel in view2,then back to view1,update the listview ?

Comment: Yes, both the Views are using same ViewModel @Tony

Comment: Yes, I mean that. I am adding the data from View2 and that should be updated in View1 @LeoZhu-MSFT

Comment: you could check the answer i post below，let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, Thanks for the help, sorry, but I could not get the chance to check it out, I will work on it this weekend and will let you know. :-)

Comment: could it work now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,here is a simple example :

in View1,there is a ListView named listview,in the View1.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class View1: ContentPage
{
    public static ObservableCollection<ViewModel> list;

    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
        list.Add(...);
        list.Add(...);
        list.Add(...);
        list.Add(...);
        list.Add(...);
        listview.ItemsSource = list;
    }
}
```

in View2,there is a button,when i click it,it will add new data into the list which in View1:

```
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        var data = new ViewModel(...);
        View1.list.Add(data);
    }
```

then when you go back to View1,the listview will update,here is use it globally by defining static，you could also use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to pass the data from View2 to View1,then receive and update the data and update the listview

Comment: Thank you for the help, I could able to get it to work by MessagingCenter. For some reason, I can not be able to initialise the ViewModel so could not use the first solution, so through messaging center, I could figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some situations like this where setting a new value to your `ObservableCollection` property doesn't update the `ListView`. It only updates the UI if you create a new `ObservableCollection`.

Try this:

```
var listFromServer = SomeService.Instance.DetailsFromServer();
if (listFromServer?.Count > 0)
{
    ListViewItemSource = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(listFromServer);
}
else
{
    ListViewItemSource = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
}
```

If it doesn't help, try to call this code when View1 is appearing.

Comment: Thank you @Dennis Schröer, but that doesn't help me. I could call it from View1 appearing but calling from OnAppearing is not allowed as of my requirements.